# Structuring an angular app for server side filtering and pagination

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, filter, pagination, angular-ui-router

tl;dr
What would be best approach for structuring an angular app which supports filtering and sorting on the server side using radio button filters on client side

**Context of the app:**

I have a sample movie list app, where movies have genre and style to categorize them. They can be sorted based on name, rating, year of release. The backend is very clear, I pass the filters to url in the form of query parameters and data is returned and pagination is also addressed. From the client side I create the url and attach the string params to it. However I have tried few implementations of filters and sorting on the client side and wasnt satisfied. every implementation involves using radio buttons for filters. The following approaches were used by me.

***Approaches used:***

1. Create few filters based on genres and styles of movies, launch an event when one radio button is clicked, pass the filter-radio model in the event. Listen for the event in a movieListDirective and then create the url followed by triggering the server  call.
2. Create filters and pass the data in a service, launch an event whenever a radio button is clicked. Listen for the event and receive the data from the service. Create the url and initiate the server call.
3. *Not yet used this approach but thinking of giving it a try*
   On click of radio button push the data in the browser url in form of query parameters. Listen for url change event inside the directive and trigger the server call

I'm also thinking of using UI router. Create an abstract state for filter and sort button. Put the movieListDirective inside the child state.

I'm just not satisfied with my 2 approaches and think that there's a huge room for improvement. Can anyone please suggest a very scalable approach or something to improve the existing approach which I'm using. Thanks in advance.

**I'm using IONIC. I would like to take advantage of the pull to refresh and infinite scroll features. These have to be put inside the ionic-content directive. Hence the approach used should satisfy this requirement **

Comment: Please add some codes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I cannot add code over here. It is too large. What I have tried is creating filters using radio buttons and directives for listing the movies. Urls for fetching movies are based on filter radio models

Comment: So please create a plnkr. Plnkr allows you to add a lot of code :)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uFXjc82B0KJ6ychwRDx7?p=preview the plunker you requested

Comment: Why not use callback params to your directive instead of events ? You can take the exemple from the angular doc : https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: the plunk is empty

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I were you I would change a variable in my `$scope` and listen its changes to request again with your filters.

I made a Plunker to help you.
https://embed.plnkr.co/cNZ1Um7FycaPBjef5LI1/

In this Plunker, I added the `ng-model` to my `radio buttons`. When these radio buttons are selected, they change my variable with their `values`.

```
<input type="radio" value="new" ng-model="area">
```

This radio button above change `$scope.area` value to `"new"`. Then, my controller listen to this change event and call my `$scope.requestAPI` function.

```
$scope.$watch('area', function() {
    $scope.requestAPI($scope.area, $scope.category);
});
```

This function use the values of `$scope.area` and `$scope.category` to make a request. Changing their values, you change the request.

It is exactly the feature that you need.